# Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class <unknown>

Tags: android

Might seem like a repost, but i've seen noone else with the same issue,

Im getting this quite often with a few of my activity's in my crash report logs.

simply at the line:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

It's extremely strange and only happens to a few users?

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager 
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
     android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />

<com.astuetz.viewpager.extensions.PagerSlidingTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dip"

    android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF" />

</RelativeLayout>

 <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="#444444"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:background="#F2323231"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: What is in "activity_main.xml"?

Comment: So usually it works but occasionally doesn't? Showing the layout XML might also be useful.

Comment: Yes exactly ^ only sometimes, and for some people.

Comment: I had similar issue once. It was a out of memory related issue. have you got full stack trace? You may see more info there.

Comment: http://crashes.to/s/e872ca1861b

Comment: @aegean Logcat above, any idea how you fixed it?

Comment: Are either of the two answers useful to you?

Comment: Not particularly, i'll accept aegans, but i'm still at a loss in terms of fixing the error.

Comment: Ah, alright. (You don't have to accept an answer if it didn't really help you.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you shared the full stack trace, base problem is `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError`. You are using an image in your layout. System tries to load it but it has not got available memory. The any image inside this layout can be the reason of the  `OutOfMemoryError` but also previously loaded images (in other contents).

You can't find direct reason by looking into stack trace for `OutOfMemoryError`s. I've solved mines with tracing my apps with [MAT](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/memory-analysis-for-android.html). (It is really hard to solve memory related problems)

Also recycle bitmaps as soon as you don't need them.

```
Caused by java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
bitmap size exceeds VM budget
```

Answer (score 0):

You should identify the relative class in .xml

```
<com.astuetz.viewpager.extensions.PagerSlidingTabStrip
    class="package.class.name.here"
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dip"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tabs"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFFFF" />
```